# Python (paramiko) - No such file or directory: u'\u012f\u0161-test.xls'

Tags: python, paramiko, ioerror

My file name is this `file_path=u'įš-test.xls`.

When I try this:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook(file_path)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'\u012f\u0161-test.xls'
```

If I change to:

```
wb = open_workbook(file_path.encode('utf-8'))

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\xc4\xaf\xc5\xa1-test.xls'
```

**Note**
There might be a problem with `paramiko`, because file is taken from remote directory, using this method (if file with unicode name is taken from local directory, it passes fine too):

```
from contextlib import closing
import socket, os
from paramiko import SSHConfig, SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy, AuthenticationException

    def check_remote_dir(self, cr, uid, ids, direct, arch_dir, gec_type, fmt, context=None):
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
        with closing(SSHClient()) as ssh:
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            try:
                ssh.connect(rec.host, username=rec.user, password=rec.password)
            except socket.gaierror:
               raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                    _("Name or service '%s' not known") % (rec.host))
            except AuthenticationException:
               raise orm.except_orm(_('Authentication Fail!'),
                    _("Bad username or password"))                    
            with closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp:
                try:
                    sftp.chdir(direct)
                except IOError:
                    raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                        _('Remote directory %s not found') % (direct)) 
                try:
                    os.chdir(arch_dir)
                except OSError:
                    raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                        _('Archive directory %s not found') % (arch_dir))                         
                gec_obj = self.pool.get('card.gec.data')
                for f in sftp.listdir():
                    for fmt in fmt.replace(' ', '').split(','): #removing any whitespace and then splitting in list
                        length = len(fmt) + 1
                        if f[-length:] == ".%s" % (fmt):
                            gec_id = gec_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name': f, 'gec_type': gec_type})
                            self._resolve_parse(cr, uid, gec_id, gec_obj, gec_type, f, context=context)
                            self.archive_file(f, None, add_dt=True, remote=True)
                            sftp.remove(f)
                            break #only need to check till first occurence
```

**P.S.** method params like `cr, uid, ids` are application specific and are not really related with remote file handling, so you can ignore those

**Update**
I noticed this in a log:

```
2015-02-03 10:23:48,143 10430 INFO amb_test paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 1] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
is-test.xls
2015-02-03 10:23:48,162 10430 INFO amb_test paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 1] sftp session closed.
```

This happens and then I get that error. Could it be that session is closed before file is used?

**Update2**
It seems something is wrong with `sftp.listdir()`. When I try to use filename from it, like using standard `open`, it gives error, that there is no such file as I guess it only checks on local directory (I don't get it how it was working before..). If I try to open with `sftp.open()`, then it works.

How could I use remote path to open it in local server?

Comment: Are you certain that you are in the correct working directory? Is the file listed in `os.listdir(u'.')`? Have you tried speficying a *full, absolute* path?

Comment: What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` state Python thinks is used for filesystem names?

Comment: @MartijnPieters as I said, it finds files if it does not have unicode characters. And I'm using full absolute path.

Comment: Right, your error message shows a relative path, I'm just eliminating the usual suspects here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters strange, I checked with ascii only name file and it gives same error, that file not found. But the thing is, when going through remote directory it actually find that file and outputs it name. But when it comes to opening it, then it gives error, saying no such file exist.

Comment: Is the filename listed in `os.listdir()`? Use a *unicode* string object to list the files and Python will decode the filenames. Have you checked for NFD vs. NFC names (Unicode allows for two codepoints to combine to form one glyph, like using a plain `e` plus [U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://codepoints.net/U+0301) form `é`. You can translate between forms if needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I might need to explain how file handling works for my approach. First it connects to remote directory, lists the files, opens them, parses data from it and saves file content (in other words, makes a copy from remote), to local archive directory. The thing is, it used to work fine, the problem occurred just now, when file was stored with unicode characters. But now even non unicode is not handled. So the problem migt be deeper.

Comment: Right; if it was *just* non-ASCII characters (the ASCII range is part of Unicode too!) I'd look into encoding differences between the local and remove system and seeing what happens when they filenames are transferred. But if you have problems with ASCII-only names now too you'll need to eliminate other problems first.

Comment: you should probably update your question to make it more focused. For example, it seems `xlrd` has nothing to do with your issue because you are having problems with remote names. Create [*minimal* (but complete) code example with `paramiko` that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was something wrong with remote file paths. When I got a remote path and tried to directly open from it, it would not see it and would throw an error that such file not found.

So I rewritten my methods, to handle remote files a bit differently. Now it just downloads it and opens it locally, instead of remotely (and only after parsing saving it locally).

*If there are better approaches, please feel free to post them as answers.*
So here my new methods that solved my problem:

```
def check_remote_dir(self, cr, uid, ids, rem_dir, local_dir, arch_dir, gec_type, fmt, context=None):
    """
    Only used to check remote directories and download files
    locally
    """
    rec = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    with closing(SSHClient()) as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
            ssh.connect(rec.host, username=rec.user, password=rec.password)
        except socket.gaierror:
           raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                _("Name or service '%s' not known") % (rec.host))
        except AuthenticationException:
           raise orm.except_orm(_('Authentication Fail!'),
                _("Bad username or password"))                    
        with closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp:
            try:
                sftp.chdir(rem_dir)
            except IOError:
                raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                    _('Remote directory %s not found') % (rem_dir)) 
            try:
                os.chdir(local_dir)
            except OSError:
                raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
                    _('Archive directory %s not found') % (arch_dir))                         
            gec_obj = self.pool.get('card.gec.data')
            for f in sftp.listdir():
                sftp.get(f, f)
                sftp.remove(f)
    #handle files locally
    rec.check_dir(local_dir, arch_dir, gec_type, fmt)  

def check_dir(self, cr, uid, ids, direct, arch_dir, gec_type, formats, context=None):
    rec = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    try:
        os.chdir(direct)
    except OSError:
        raise orm.except_orm(_('Error!'),
            _('Directory %s not found') % (direct))                
    directs = os.listdir(direct)
    gec_obj = self.pool.get('card.gec.data')
    formats = formats.replace(' ', '').split(',') # Removing any whitespace and then splitting in list
    for f in directs:
        for fmt in formats: 
            length = len(fmt) + 1
            if f[-length:] == ".%s" % (fmt):
                gec_id = gec_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name': f, 'gec_type': gec_type})
                self._resolve_parse(cr, uid, gec_id, gec_obj, gec_type, f, context=context)
                self.archive_file(f, arch_dir, add_dt=True)
                break #only need to check till first occurence
```